# Code giving unexpected output in c

Tags: c

The following code snippet gives unexpected output in Turbo C++ compiler:

```
     char a[]={'a','b','c'};
     printf("%s",a);
```

Why doesn't this print `abc`? In my understanding, strings are implemented as one dimensional character arrays in C.
Secondly, what is the difference between `%s` and `%2s`?

Comment: This case is pretty obvious, but in the future it would help to tell us what the program *is* doing (other than "not working") in addition to what you *expect* it to do; otherwise we can only guess as to what the problem may be.

Answer (score 5):

This is because your string is not zero-terminated. This will work:

```
char a[]={'a','b','c', '\0'};
```

The `%2s` specifies the minimum width of the printout. Since you are printing a 3-character string, this will be ignored. If you used `%5s`, however, your string would be padded on the left with two spaces.

Answer (score 3):

```
char a[]={'a','b','c'};
```

Well one problem is that strings need to be null terminated:

```
char a[]={'a','b','c', 0};
```

Answer (score 2):

Without change the original char-array you can also use

```
     char a[]={'a','b','c'};
     printf("%.3s",a);
or
     char a[]={'a','b','c'};
     printf("%.*s",sizeof(a),a);
or
     char a[]={'a','b','c'};
     fwrite(a,3,1,stdout);
or
     char a[]={'a','b','c'};
     fwrite(a,sizeof(a),1,stdout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you aren't using a string. To be considered as a string you need the 'null termination': '\0' or 0 (yes, without quotes).

You can achieve this by two forms of initializations:

```
char a[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
```

or using the compiler at your side:

```
char a[] = "abc";
```

Comment: That zero escaped with a backslash is perfectly fine, it represents (char)0, which terminates the string. I don't see the reason for downvoting. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we store a string in c programming, we always have one extra character at the end to identify the end of the string.

The Extra character used is the `null` character `'\0'`.
In your above program you are missing the null character.

You can define your string as

```
char a[] = "abc";
```

to get the desired result.